# Switching activities using buttons in a main activity with a navigation drawer

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, navigation

I've looked up quite a few of the questions asked about the navigation drawer and buttons and many of them are geared towards the button used for the navigation drawer itself. My question is that I can't get a button move to the next activity from the main activity that has a navigation drawer. It creates the button but the clicker doesn't move to the following activity, nor will it throw a toast to let me know that the clicker is working.

I used the template that eclipse gives you when you create a new navigation drawer.

```
public class UserMain extends Activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

Button one;

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_main);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    System.out.println("Button1");
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //There is a problem here!!!

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println(v.toString());

            System.out.println("Button 1 pressed!");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "ONE";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast passwordToast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            passwordToast.show();
        }
    });

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

}

Comment: This is way too much code, most of it irrelevant to the question. You might want to trim it to the relevant parts so others could easily parse your question.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that out @Ugo

Comment: i guess what you are trying to say is about the back navigation from one activity to another from the home button that looks as an arrow??

Comment: @KostasMatrix I'm trying to create a button in an activity that has a navigation drawer that will, based off the given code, throw a toast.

Comment: your navigation drawer returns some fragment depending on the listview length and position..In the particular fragment that you would like to put the button you will go to the fragment's layout and inflate it through getview() method.

Comment: @KostasMatrix So rather than putting the button in the activity, put it in the first fragment and inflate it?

Comment: yes...but you dont have to put it necesserilly in the first fragment....any fragment you want...

Comment: @Derpafox Glad for help!!!